# TypeScript: "Cannot use namespace as a type"

Tags: typescript, types, module

Note: All other issues here on SO that I've found are Angular related and/or have an entirely different setup than this.

---

I have the following setup:

`inner/action.ts`:

```js
export type MyAction = string;
```

`inner/functions.ts`

```js
import { MyAction } from "./action";

const identity = (action: MyAction): string => action;

export {
    identity
};
```

`inner/index.ts`

```js
import * as MyAction from "./functions";

export { MyAction };
export * from "./action";
```

`usage.ts`

```js
import { MyAction } from "./inner";

const action: MyAction = "";
//            ^___ error is here
```

> Error: Cannot use namespace 'MyAction' as a type

Though IntelliJ offers to navigate to that place in code.

Why is it not allowed to use this the same name in both cases and what can I do to have them both with the same name?

Comment: Doesn't `import * as MyAction` mean you've made a namespace `MyAction` that holds all the exported stuff?  So that means now you have `MyAction.MyAction` as a type.  e.g., `import { MyAction } from...` lets you do `const a: MyAction`, but `import * as Foo from ...` lets you do `const a: Foo.MyAction`.

Comment: If I type `const action: MyAction.MyAction = "";` it says `Namespace ...functions has no exported member 'MyAction'`. Also, I cannot use any combination with `import * as Foo` either.

Comment: Yes, you’re not exporting anything from `functions`.  I’m not sure why you’re setting up a big chain of export/imports instead of just having everything import from one place, but that’s up to you I guess. But if you want to import from `functions` you will need to export something from it.

Comment: I've edited with the export. I am doing this, because this way I have a consistent namespace. This way the environment can help me when I type `MyAction` - it shows it's related functions too. `import * as MyAction` would force me to give names to imports in individual files. I am using this method over `namespace` keyword so that I can make `1 file = 1 function` rule and still have 'namespace'.

Comment: This example was meant to be about importing both and I have forgotten to add the export to the `functions.ts` for this little reproducable example. It does not change anything actually.

Comment: So is the issue that `inner/index.ts` is trying to export two different things named `MyAction` and the explicitly named one (i.e., `export { MyAction};`) is overwriting the implicitly named one from the re-export (i.e., `export * from "./action";`), and you were expecting a merge instead of an overwrite?  I don't have much insight here, I'm afraid.  Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is in `inner/index.ts`
by doing:

```
import * as MyAction from "./functions";

export { MyAction };
```

what you're doing is exporting a namespace called `MyAction` which includes all exports of `function.ts`
This means that the value of MyAction exported by `inner/index.ts` is

```
{
    identity: (action)=>action
}
```

this value overrides the value of `MyAction` exported from `action.ts` in the line

```
export * from "./action";
```

instead what you need to do is

```
export * from "./functions";
export * from "./action";
```

This will export both `identity` and `MyAction` without any renaming or namespacing